# Symbols visible in EXE file without PDB

Tags: symbols, debugging-symbols, pdb

I imported my exe file in OllyDB and when I searched for the names(labels) present, I was able to see all the function declarations, class names etc. I didn't have my PDB in the EXE path. Why does this occur? Should I enable some obfuscation settings during my build?

Comment: Was the .pdb in the search path?

Comment: No, the PDB was not in the search path.

Comment: Are you using RTTI ?

Comment: Yes,  I have used dynamic_cast<> in my code. But is that an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is probably the issue and definitely should be at least part of it. Would you post some examples of suspicious strings that you see in the code ?

Comment: I could see all sharedPtr declarations along with other class names. One thing I wanted to know is, will symbols be a part of binary as well in Windows build? I was trying to see if using BINPLACE could remove the symbols off the binary. Is there any other way of stripping these symbols?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the full path to the original PDB is baked in to the exe. So even if the pdb is not in the same directory as the running binary, if it exists at the build location, the debugger can still find it.

Comment: The PDB is not there in the build location.

Answer (score 5):

`dynamic_cast` requires a [runtime check that the cast is valid at execution time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and the usual implementation uses [RTTI (Run-time type information)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) attached to all classes participating in the casts. However, since it's not easy to narrow down the classes that may be possibly casted, in practice the compiler emits RTTI for *all* polymorphic classes (i.e. those that have virtual methods). While the RTTI details are not specified by the C++ standard, the Visual C++ implementation retains full class names. You can find more details in [my article on the topic](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23).